# How to change which layout is showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner

I am making an app where there is a spinner where you can choose 1 of 4 options. i want it so that if you click option a an image a layout is drawn below and if you pick option b a different layout is drawn, I have tried setting the layouts to invisible and making it so that when you pick a topic that layout becomes visible but the problem is when I need that layout to disappear it doesn't

here is my code, this code just makes both appear when I chose an option from the spinner

```
 if (pos == 1){

            cooldown.setVisibility(0);
            warmup.setVisibility(1);

        }else if (pos == 2){
            cooldown.setVisibility(1);
            warmup.setVisibility(0);
        }
```

I think the setvisibility is a dead end

Comment: Are you just changing an image?

Comment: you should probably be using an activity for each option in your spinner.

Comment: Or use one activity with 4 fragments and make use of LayoutInflater

Answer (score 2):

The parameter for `setVisibility()` should not be hard coded 0 or 1. There are constants for that. `VISIBLE` is 0, `INVISIBLE` is 4, and `GONE` is 8. Passing in 1 doesn't do anything.
[See here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

In your case you should use `VISIBLE` and `GONE` since `INVISIBLE` will still take layout space.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't the correct constants for `visibility`. Try instead

```
 if (pos == 1){

        cooldown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        warmup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }else if (pos == 2){
        cooldown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        warmup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

[Visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

If these are single images then this is how you want to do it. If they are complete `Layouts` with many `Views` then you will probably want to consider using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE** instead the number